# jquery / css label selector not working in ie7

Tags: jquery, css

i have some hidden radio buttons which are selected when click on the labels but in ie7 does not seems to select the radio when clicking on the label any ideas why?

```
jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
            if (jQuery(this).val()=='2') {
                jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label").removeClass();
                jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label i").hide();
                jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label i").show();
                jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label").addClass("active");
            } else {
                jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label").removeClass();
                jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label i").hide();
                jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label i").show();
                jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label").addClass("active");
            }
```

css

```
fieldset.account-type ul li input { position: absolute; left: -999999em; }
```

html

```
<ul>
  <li class="input" id="user_type_2_wrapper">
    <label>
      <i class="icon icon-ok" style="display: none;"></i>
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="user[role_ids][]" id="user_role_ids__2"> as a <b>Host</b><br><span>A Host is the person who wants to run events or tenders.</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="input" id="user_type_3_wrapper">
    <label>
      <i class="icon icon-ok" style="display: none;"></i>
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="user[role_ids][]" id="user_role_ids__3"> as a <b>Participant</b><br><span>A Participant is someone who wants to take part in an event or tender process.</span>
     </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add HTML so we can see the markup.

Comment: opps sorry, let me add now

Comment: Are you using jQuery version 2.x, which doesn't support IE 6-8?

Comment: no it is not using jquery 2.x but 1.* everything else works fine, just seems not this - i manage to fix on ie8 by change the css for the label not to use display: none but ie7 i still have an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [label-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) a bit wrong, they need the for-attribute which contains the id of the radiobutton which they are label for. And the text needs to be inside the label, like so:

```
    <input type="radio" value="3" id="user_role_ids__3" />
    <label for="user_role_ids__3">as a <b>Participant</b></label>
```

Comment: wow i would not normally miss that! its because its all in ruby and im not a ruby guy so did not spot it - thanks! will try it now haha

Comment: yep was fine, sorry - shocked i missed it!